# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: PersonDetail while using starlette fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

table is found but still getting the table not found error
where my  main file is
main.py

```
import uvicorn
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.routing import Route
from API.get import GetMethod
from API.post import PostMethod
from db import engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
routes = [Route("/get", endpoint=GetMethod, methods=["GET"]),
          Route("/post", endpoint=PostMethod, methods=["POST"]),
          ]
app = Starlette(
    routes=routes
)
@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("carsharing:app", reload=True)
```

Database table file and schemas.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
class PersonDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PersonDetail'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

get.py is

```
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import PlainTextResponse, JSONResponse, RedirectResponse, Response
from db import engine
from schemas import PersonDetail
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
local_session = Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)
def GetMethod(request):
    return local_session.query(PersonDetail).all()
```

Database file is
db.py is

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(
    "sqlite:///PersonalDetail.db",
    connect_args={"check_same_thread": False},
    echo=True)


def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're creating multiple instances of `Base` - but only you're only running `create_all` for one of them. Make sure to use the same `Base` for all your models and your `create_all` call. I'm also not sure where you import your models (your schemas.py - usually schemas describe the input/output mappings in FastAPI and not your database models) before calling `create_all`.

Comment: Getting an operational error as there is no table created. How to resolve this